# Write custome wc_downloadable_product_permissions

Tags: woocommerce

In `wc-order-functions.php` there is the function `wc_downloadable_product_permissions` which generates the download permissions.

```php
/**
 * Order Status completed - give downloadable product access to customer.
 *
 * @param int  $order_id Order ID.
 * @param bool $force    Force downloadable permissions.
 */
function wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id, $force = false ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if ( ! $order || ( $order->get_data_store()->get_download_permissions_granted( $order ) && ! $force ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( $order->has_status( 'processing' ) && 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_downloads_grant_access_after_payment' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items()
```

How can I overwrite this function? I had a look at the actions hooks, but I think for the moment it would be best if I could directly replace this function within a plugin.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can work with hooks only. Replacing a function is not possible with not changing the code at all. I saw that the function get's hooked at two places: `woocommerce_order_status_completed` and `woocommerce_order_status_processing`. You could remove the function from each hook and add your own - thats all I think.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the default woocomerce actions and instead hook your own code.

```php
if( !class_exists('MyPlugin') ):
class MyPlugin{

  public function wc_downloadable_product_permissions( $order_id, $force = false ) {
    // own code
  }

  public function plugin_setting(){

    // remove default woocomerce action and replace them with custom action

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions' );

    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', [$this, 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions'] );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing', [$this, 'wc_downloadable_product_permissions'] );
```